# AngularJS : Regex nothing to repeat error

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to replace some words (all the words present in my rootscope data array) for add a tooltip.

My code :

```
.directive('replaceDirective', function($rootScope, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            //For exemple
            //$rootScope.data = ["word1", "word2", "word3", etc..]; 

            var test = {
                getTest: function(e, word) {
                    return RegExp(e.toString().replace(/\bxx\b/g, "").replace(/xx/g, word), "g")
                }
            };

            scope.$watch(attrs.replaceDirective, function(html) {
                for (var i=0; i<$rootScope.data.length; i++) {
                    var tooltipWord = $rootScope.data[i].word;
                    var tooltipDescription = $rootScope.data[i].def;
                    var template = '<a data-html="true" class="tooltip" title="' + tooltipDescription + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" tooltip>' + tooltipWord + '</a>';

                    var oldRegex = /\bxx\b/;
                    html = html.replace(test.getTest(oldRegex, tooltipWord), template);
                }

                element.html(html);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It doesn't work! I have an error.

The error is:

```
"Error: nothing to repeat  
   .link/test.getTest@file:www/js/directives.js:336:28  
   .link/<@file:www/js/directives.js:357:76"
```

Comment: I saw a single double quotes here `html = html.replace(test.getTest(oldRegex, tooltipWord), template");`

Comment: Just look at the code highlighting in the code block in your question. Specifically, the last few lines. You have a stray `"` there that you'd have seen in any IDE with syntax highlighting.

Comment: It just an copy/past error. I will edit my post!

Comment: The problem is with forming the dynamic regex part. "Nothing to repeat" appears when you set the quantifier after another quantifier (e.g. `(text)*+`). Just make sure you [escape the metacharacters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) in your regex before testing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with forming the dynamic regex part. "Nothing to repeat" erro appears when you set the quantifier after another quantifier, anchor or alternation operator.

So, perhaps, your regex starts looking like `(text)*+`, or `(a|?b)`, or `*\s+`.

To fix this, make sure you [escape the metacharacters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) in your regex before testing.

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\[\]\/{}()*+?.\\^$|-]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

And

```
getTest: function(e, word) {
 return RegExp(escapeRegExp(e.toString().replace(/\bxx\b/g, "").replace(/xx/g, word)), "g")
}
```